# The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 4.2.5 and I am follow this document https://www.sitepoint.com/youtube-rails/
Since here there is regular expression are used to validate a **youtube** url. I am copy paste it in my rails application its working fine on rails console

```
[1] pry(main)> YT_LINK_FORMAT = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([\w-]{10,})/
=> /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([\w-]{10,})/
[2] pry(main)> video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZngT1Eas4w"
=> "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZngT1Eas4w"
[3] pry(main)> uid = video_url.match(YT_LINK_FORMAT)
=> #<MatchData "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZngT1Eas4w" 1:"aZngT1Eas4w">
[4] pry(main)> uid[2]
=> nil
[5] pry(main)> uid[1]
=> "aZngT1Eas4w"
[6] pry(main)> video_url = "https://youtu.be/aZngT1Eas4w"
=> "https://youtu.be/aZngT1Eas4w"
[7] pry(main)> uid = video_url.match(YT_LINK_FORMAT)
=> #<MatchData "https://youtu.be/aZngT1Eas4w" 1:"aZngT1Eas4w">
[8] pry(main)> uid[1]
=> "aZngT1Eas4w"
```

But when I run my rails application I got this error

```
"The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?"
```

I am also try to use this regular expression

```
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([\w-]{10,})/
=> /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([\w-]{10,})/
```

But the same problem is still there

Comment: `/\A(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([\w-]{10,})/` the reason is Rails tries to prevent you from injections.

Comment: If I am replace ^ to \A then it always be true for any url like this 
'https://www.aaaaa.com/watch?v=o3m2F6CDktc'

Comment: I try your '/\A(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch‌​\?v=)?([\w-]{10,})/' but it is not working

Answer (score -1):

This regular expression is working for rails 5

```
YT_LINK_FORMAT = /(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|)(www.)?(youtu(be\.com|\.be|be\.com))\/(video\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|v\/)?([A-Za-z0-9._%-]*)(\&\S+)?/
```

Comment: This is dangerous and NOT robust. It matches whatever _containing_ the string. And yes, the regular expression I provided **perfectly works**.

Comment: Are you try your answer with rails application. ANd why are you make my answer to negative always. Your regular experession not bw working anymore. Why it is so dangerous. It is working fine for youtube url. Try the app with rails Rails 4.2.5 and ruby 2.3.0. your regular expression not be working anymore

Comment: have a look to my question. My regular expression also be working on console but in rails app it give us a error and your expression is not working for youtube url.

Comment: @jailalawat what error? It doesn't work for what input?

Comment: @mudasobwa Here is the output for your best expression and congratulates it is not working 
'[2] pry(main)> YT_LINK_FORMAT = /\A(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch‌​\?v=)?([\w-]{10,})/
=> /\A(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?youtu(?:\.be|be\.com)\/(?:watch\u200C\u200B\?v=)?([\w-]{10,})/ '

'[3] pry(main)> video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZngT1Eas4w"
=> "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZngT1Eas4w"'

'[4] pry(main)> uid = video_url.match(YT_LINK_FORMAT)'
'=> nil'
[5] pry(main)> '

Comment: @mudasobwa: your regex looks good on the site, BUT when copy-pasted, it contains four bytes of unprintable chars in the middle. See [here](https://monosnap.com/file/hIvouVGjIlXMtrJTXx5Wt4CilhMT3p.png). Not sure if stackoverflow's fault or interference from your mad unicode skills :) If we remove these bytes, it works great.

Comment: @jailalawat: that is unreadable. Post this to gist, or something.

Comment: @jailalawat: what mudasobwa meant is that your regex will match string like "alsdkjfa;lsdkfja;lsdfjahttps://youtu.be/aZngT1Eas4w", which is NOT a youtube url.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have no specific unicode skills :) This is not the first time I notice SO ruins a code in comments, no idea why. I can’t find the previous case now, but probably I should^W will provide a bug report.